# Sort Array of String by Index

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How can I sort my array of strings by index either ascending or descending:

```
var arr = ['heck', 'yeah', 'soon', 'greet'];

return arr.slice(0, 10).sort((a, b) => b > a).map(function(tag){
   console.log(tag);
});
```

I can't use length here cause by default it will sort it via length.

Any idea?

Comment: please add the wanted result. which index do you mean?

Comment: asc : `arr.sort()` desc : `arr.sort(); arr.reverse();`

Comment: @headmaxL got it.

Comment: By _"sort by index"_ you mean _"sort alphabetically"_?

Answer (score 0):

The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place. The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points. So you can use

acs:

```
arr.sort()
```

desc:

```
arr.sort(); 
arr.reverse();
```